# How to merge files based on a common column?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

There are 2 files, file1 is the output of a telnet command i.e.

```
25-08-2019 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ]  
25-08-2019 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ]
```

and another is the file2, which is like

```
http://ip1:port1/, ZOOM1  
http://ip2:port2/, ZOOM2  
http://ip3:port3/, ZOOM3
```

I need to merge these 2 files based on common IP and port. The output should be a 3rd file like:

```
25-08-2019 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ]  ZOOM1  
25-08-2019 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ]  ZOOM2
```

I tried `join`, but `join` gives errors in my shell. Any help *without* `join` would be highly helpful.

I tried `join`, this works as a command line, but fails in a shell script, both in `bash` and `sh`. Moreover it does not match, it just copy-pastes.

`paste -d " : " file1 <(cut -s -d ',' -f2 file2)`

I also tried the `awk` command, but it does not process files as expected.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,h[$2]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: *I tried join, but join gives errors in my shell* - how did you try it?

Comment: Your `awk` attempt was on the right track: `awk 'NR==FNR {h[gensub(",","",1,$1)] = $2; next} {print $0,h[$7]}' file2 file1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `awk` but it would be easier with the same separator in both file. Thus first remove the comma in `file2`:

```
sed -i.old 's/,//' file2
```

The you can process with:

```
awk '{

    if(FILENAME=="file1"){
        m[$7]=$0
    }
    else {
        if(m[$1]!=""){
           print m[$1],$2
        }
    }
}' file1 file2
```

it first registers the content of `file1` into a map with a key on the `http://...` and a value that contains the full line (`$0`). Then it processes `file2` and displays what is expected if the second column of `file2` corresponds to a key of the map.

In your particular case, you can do all in one line with:

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{

    if(FILENAME=="file1"){
        m[$7]=$0
    }
    else {
        if(m[$1]!=""){
           print m[$1],$2
        }
    }
}' file1 file2
```

Both space and comma are considered as separator by awk

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xiawi, it wroked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using `join` is a bit complicated because the two files have different delimiters, but:

```
$ join -17 -21 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,2.2 <(sort -k7,7 a.txt) <(sort -k1,1 -t, b.txt | tr -d ',')
25-08-2019 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ] ZOOM1
25-08-2019 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ] ZOOM2
```

If the files are already sorted based on the URL, the `sort` bits can be removed, though you still need to strip the commas from the second file.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %z = split/[, \n]+/, qx(cat file2);  # read file2 into %z for lookups
my @file1 = split/\n/, qx(cat file1);   # read lines of file1 into @file1
for( @file1 ){                          # for each line of file1
  /http\S+/;                     # find the url, \S+ is non-space chars
  print "$_ $z{$&}\n";           # url in $& print the line and "the zoom" from %z
}
```

Replace `file1` and `file2` with `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]` if you want to get the filenames from the command line. I don't know if `/usr/bin/parse` and `awk` could work in this situation like you suggest. Would be interesting to see how. Perl is superior to awk in most cases.

Comment: Hi Kjetli, Thanks a lot for prompt answer, I ran the above solution as .sh file, and got below error, my shell is bash.                                                                                                     
test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 1: `my %h = split/[, \n]+/, qx(cat file2);'

Comment: @Novice  I added `#!/usr/bin/perl` as the first line now. Save my answer into `merge.pl` for example and `chmod +x merge.pl`. Now you should be able to run: `./merge.pl` and if that doesn't work run: `perl merge.pl`. (All three files should be in the current directory: merge.pl, file1 and file2)

Answer (score 1):

Read `file2` into a hash and then process `file1` a line at a time, extracting the key and looking it up in your hash. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;

my %data_hash = map { split /,/ } <$fh2>;

close $fh2;

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;

while (<$fh1>) {
  if (my ($key) = /\b(http:\S+)/) {
    if (exists $data_hash{$key}) {
      chomp;
      print "$_ $data_hash{$key}";
    } else {
      # Key doesn't exist in file2
      print;
    }
  } else {
    # No http key found on a line in file1
    print;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1]=$2; next} {print $0" "h[$7]}' <(sed "s/,//" file2) file1
```

Result:

```
25-08-2019 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ] ZOOM1
25-08-2019 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ] ZOOM2
```